# C# generics: Simplify type signature

Tags: c#, generics

If I have a generic Item class that looks like this:

```
abstract class Item<T>
{
}
```

And a Container of Items that looks like this:

```
class Container<TItem, T>
    where TItem : Item<T>
{
}
```

Since TItem depends on T, is it possible to simplify the type signature of Container so that it takes only one type parameter? What I really want is something this:

```
class Container<TItem>
    where TItem : Item   // this doesn't actually work, because Item takes a type parameter
{
}
```

So I can instantiate it as follows:

```
class StringItem : Item<string>
{
}

var good = new Container<StringItem>();
var bad = new Container<StringItem, string>();
```

The compiler should be able to deduce that T is string when TItem is StringItem, right? How do I make this happen?

Desired usage:

```
class MyItem : Item<string>
{
}

Container<MyItem> container = GetContainer();
MyItem item = container.GetItem(0);
item.MyMethod();
```

Comment: I think you can. Its polymorphism. You can override abstract methods.

Comment: In that case you may create StringContainer class  as   class StringContainer<TItem>
    where TItem : Item<string>

Comment: I don't believe the compiler can _partially_ infer generic types.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not possible...

Comment: @DStanley: Sadly, I think you may be right.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want I think. Obviously you're now doing `Container<string>` not `Container<StringItem>` but as you've not included usage examples I can't see it being a problem.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myContainer = new Container<string>();

            myContainer.MyItems = new List<Item<string>>();
        }
    }

    public class Item<T> { }

    public class Container<T>
    {
        // Just some property on your container to show you can use Item<T>
        public List<Item<T>> MyItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How about this revised version:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myContainer = new Container<StringItem>();

            myContainer.StronglyTypedItem = new StringItem();
        }
    }

    public class Item<T> { }

    public class StringItem : Item<string> { }

    // Probably a way to hide this, but can't figure it out now
    // (needs to be public because it's a base type)
    // Probably involves making a container (or 3rd class??)
    // wrap a private container, not inherit it
    public class PrivateContainer<TItem, T> where TItem : Item<T> { }

    // Public interface
    public class Container<T> : PrivateContainer<Item<T>, T>
    {
        // Just some property on your container to show you can use Item<T>
        public T StronglyTypedItem { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This compiles, but I really need Container<TItem>, not Container<T>.

Comment: @brianberns: Why? (Not complaining, just would be useful for potential answers)

Comment: Usage gets complex, but imagine that there's a method on Container called GetItem(int index) that has to return a TItem, not an Item<T>. This allows the caller to invoke TItem methods directly on the result, without having to cast it from Item<T> to TItem.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Isn't `T` in Container going to derive from `Item<T>` now? In other words, `List<T>` would be a `List<StringItem>` in the example case, not a `List<string>`. I think this would work if you declared `myContainer` as an instance of `Container<string>` instead though.

Comment: I like the PrivateContainer idea, but I need Container<TItem>, not Container<T>.

Comment: T will derive from `Item<T>` now, e.g. StringItem, I thought that was what you wanted when you spoke about `TItem` and `GetItem` (i.e. `GetItem` would return a `StringItem`.

Comment: I need StronglyTypedItem to be a TItem, not a T.

Answer (score 1):

I think one possible solution to your problem is adding interface `IItem` and the code structure will be like following.

```
interface IItem { }

abstract class Item<T> : IItem { }

class Container<TItem> where TItem : IItem { }

class StringItem: Item<string> { }
```

And now you can have the `Container<StringItem>`:

```
var container = new Container<StringItem>();
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but the problem with this is that Container really needs to know about TItem's underlying T parameter.

Comment: Then it is not possible.