# Java generics - inferring nested type

Tags: java, generics, language-design

I have defined following classes:

```
class Operation<S>
class GetReservationOperation extends Operation<Reservation>
```

Now I would like to have a class like this:

```
OperationExecutor<T extends Operation<S>> extends AsyncTask<T,Void,S>{
    @Override
    protected S doInBackground(T... params) {
       return null;
    }
}
```

But this won't compile:

```
OperationExecutor<GetReservationOperation> executor = new ....
```

Why doesn't Java allow this?

After some time I came up with the following solution:

```
OperationExecutor<T extends Operation<S>,S> extends AsyncTask<T,Void,S>{
    @Override
    protected S doInBackground(T... params) {
       return null;
    }
}
```

But this forces me to write the following:

```
OperationExecutor<GetReservationOperation,Reservation> executor = new ....
```

Which looks odd. Is there any way to make it look nicer?

**EDIT** 
This worked

```
OperationExecutor<S> extends AsyncTask<Operation<S>,Void,S>{
    @Override
    protected S doInBackground(Operation<S>... params) {
       return null;
    }
}

OperationExecutor<Reservation> executor = new ....
executor.execute(getReservationOperation);
```

Comment: That's the reason why the keyword `var` is so useful in C#. Unfortunately java seems to lack that.

Comment: So what's hiding behind `...`? The same as your declaration?

Comment: @HighCore Which isn't really relevant so....

Comment: Nope, there's no way to make that nicer. :( It's a limitation in the type system, for sure.

Comment: FYI C# has the [same limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086708/c-sharp-generics-simplify-type-signature).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I would like to have a class like this
>
> ```
> OperationExecutor<T extends Operation<S>> extends AsyncTask<T,Void,S>{
>     @Override
>     protected S doInBackground(T... params) {
>        return null;
>     }
> }
> ```

The reason this doesn't work is because `S` hasn't been *declared* anywhere, only referenced as a type argument in `T`'s bound. Java needs `S` to be declared for other references to it to make sense, for example `protected S doInBackground` and `AsyncTask<T,Void,S>`.

One thing you might consider is whether `OperationExecutor` needs to be generic to a specific type of `Operation<S>`. You could do this instead for example:

```
OperationExecutor<S> extends AsyncTask<Operation<S>, Void, S> {
    @Override
    protected S doInBackground(Operation<S>... params) {
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1778240 Right, it would need to be `OperationExecutor<Reservation>`, into which you could pass `GetReservationOperation`s or any other `Operation<Reservation>`.